# Proving an inequality regarding limit superior and limit inferior.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Exercise: Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $L^+ = \lim \sup_{n\to\infty} (a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ and $L^-=\lim \inf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. Prove that $$\inf(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty \le L^-\le L^+\le \sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$$ I have already proven that $\inf(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty\le L^-$ and $L^+\le \sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. This just follows from the definitions and the following proposition. I am not sure if my proof regarding $L^-\le L^+$ is correct or not. I would appreciate if someone could check whether it is correct or not.

Proposition $1$: Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. If $y<\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$, then there exists an $n$ such that $y<a_n\le \sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. Similarly if $y>\inf(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$, then there exists an $n$ such that $y>a_n\ge \inf(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$.

Notation: The sequence $(a^+ _N)_{n=m}^\infty$ is the sequence defined by the formula $$a^+ _N :=\sup(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$$

The sequence $(a^- _N)_{N=m}^\infty$ is the sequence defined by the formula $$a^- _N:=\inf(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$$ These are essentially the sequences from where the definition of limit superior and limit inferior come from. I think different books use different notation. This is the one used in the book I am reading. So, the book defines $$\lim \sup_{n\to\infty}(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty := \inf(a^+ _N)_{N=m}^\infty$$ $$\lim\inf_{n\to\infty} (a_n)_{n=m}^\infty := \sup(a^- _N)_{N=m}^\infty$$

---

The following is the proof of $L^-\le L^+$.

Proof: First we prove that $a^+ _N\ge a^- _N$ for all $N$. By definition we have that $a^+_N=\sup(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$ and $a^- _N=\inf(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$. Thus, we need to prove that $\sup(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty \ge \inf(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$. If $\sup(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty=\inf(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$, then we are done. So suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\inf(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty >\sup(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$. Then by definition of supremum we have that for all $n$,   $$\inf(a_n)_{n=N}>\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty \ge a_n$$ Which contradicts the definition of the infimum of a sequence. Thus, $$\sup(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty \ge \inf(a_n)_{n=N}^\infty$$

Now to prove that $L^-\le L^+$, we have to show that $$\sup(a^-_N)_{N=m}^\infty \le \inf(a^+_N)_{N=m}^\infty $$ If they are both equal, then we are done. So, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $$\sup(a^-_N)_{N=m}^\infty > \inf(a^+_N)_{N=m}^\infty$$ Then by proposition $1$, there exists an $N$ such that $$\sup(a^-_N)> a^+_N\ge \inf(a^+_N)_{N=m}^\infty$$ Then again by proposition $1$ there exists an $N'$ such that $$\sup(a^-_N)_{N=m}^\infty \ge a^-_{N'}>a^+_N\ge \inf(a^+_N)_{N=m}^\infty$$ But this contradicts the previous result that $a^+_N\ge a^-_N$ for all $N$. Thus, we have that $$L^-\le L^+$$

---

Is this proof correct? If so, is there a simpler way to prove this inequality?

Comment: The LHS of the book's def'ns of $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ don't make sense. $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}a_n$ is just an abbreviation for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\,(\sup_{m\ge n}a_m)$ and similarly for the $\lim\inf$. Your work is good. This is a useful special case (with $U_N=a^+_N$ and $D_N=a^-_N$) that if $D_N\le U_N$ forall $N,$ where $U_N$ converges to $U$ and $D_N$ converges to $D$ then $U\ge D$. Including the cases $U=\pm\infty$ or $D=\pm\infty$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I’m not sure. This was from the book Analysis $1$ by Terence Tao. He defines the limit superior and inferior the way I defined in the post.

Comment: I think the problem is that Tao's "$n\to\infty$" appears under $\sup$ or $\inf$ when everyone else puts it under, or just after, $\lim.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah that could be it. Anyways, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Whether or not you can simplify it depends on if and how you've defined suprema/infima for subsets of ordered fields.